# Stein and Shakarchi complex analysis exercise 8 chapter 3

Tags: complex-analysis

For the following problem:
[image: page1]

I considered the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^{n+1}}$ which is holomorphic except for poles at $ i$ and $-i$.
So I considered a semi-circular contour,

[image: page2]

I have the residue of $\int_{\gamma_{R}} f(z) dz = \frac{\pi}{(2i)^n}$

If $C_R$ is the large semicircle of radius $R$, we have that $|\int_{C_R} f(z) dz| \leq \frac{M}{R^{2n+1}}$, so $R \to \infty$, the integral goes to zero.

Therefore now we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \frac{\pi}{(2i)^n}$ which is not what should be proved. I would appreciate if someone can point where I am going wrong.

Based on the feedback below, I have the residue as :
$2 \pi i(\lim_{z \to i} \frac {1}{(n!)} (\frac{d}{dz})^{n} (z-i)^n f(z))$ =
$2 \pi i(\frac {1}{(n!)} \frac {(-1)^n(n+1)(n+2)....(2n)}{(2i)^{n+1}})$
=$\frac{i^n(n+1)(n+2)......(2n)}{2.4.6......2n} . \pi$

But I dont have the final answer.
I would appreciate some feedback on this.

Comment: Your residue computation is wrong. If $g$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $z_0$ with $g(z_0) \neq 0$, then the residue of $\frac{g(z)}{(z - z_0)^{n+1}}$ at $z_0$ is the coefficient of $(z - z_0)^n$ in the Taylor series of $g$, i.e. $\frac{g^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\oint_{C_R}\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^{n+1}}dz=\oint_{C_R}\frac{\frac{1}{(z+i)^{n+1}}}{(z-i)^{n+1}}dz$. Write $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+i)^{n+1}}$. Then $f'(z)=-\frac{n+1}{(z+i)^{n+2}},\, f''(z)=(-1)^2\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(z+i)^{n+3}},\dots,f^{(n)}(z)=(-1)^{n}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}{(z+i)^{2n+1}}$.

Since $f$ is holomorphic at $z=i$, expand it in a Taylor series. The only meaningful term is at the $nth$ derivative. All other terms in the Taylor series integrate to zero due to $\frac{f(z)}{(z-i)^{n+1}}$ having an anti derivative.

Comment: Thank you @zugzug. I dint understand how all the other terms in the taylor series integrate to zero other than the nth term. I am assuming we integrate term by term. Also, now how do I calculate the residue?

Comment: Because functions of the form $C(z-i)^M$ have an anti-derivative for $M\neq -1$ (this includes positive and negative integers). At $M=-1$, there is a problem because the derivative of $\log$ does not exist everywhere around the circle. On the terms where the anti-derivative exists, you are evaluating the anti-derivative around a closed loop, which integrates to zero.

Comment: In your problem, the $n$th term in the Taylor series leads to something of the form $\frac{C}{z-i}$. The constant $C$ is the residue.

Comment: Can I get a more complete answer above? Why does $f^(n)(z)$ have an antiderivative? What is the complete taylor expansion? @zugzug. I am learning this stuff. Also shouldnt this integral be over the curve $\gamma$ not $C_R$

Comment: What is the antiderivative of $C(z-i)^M$ for $M\neq -1$?

Comment: It is $C(z-i)^{(M+1)}/M+1$